# Does a native php (5+) function exist that does the following in 1 line?

Tags: php, arrays

```
function array_value_from_key($array,$key)
{
     return !empty($array[$key]) ? $array[$key] : null;
}
```

The reason I ask is because I have a class function that returns an array.

Instead of having to do

```
$myArray = myClass::giveMeArray();
$myValue = $myArray[$myKey];
```

I'd like to do something along the lines of

```
$myValue = array_value_from_key(myClass::giveMeArray(),$myKey);
```

When an object is returned, you can chain the object such as

```
$myValue = myClass::giveMeObject()->aValue;
```

Voila, nice and clean..  not being able to find what seems to be a simple and trivial function is driving me crazy...

PS.. one more example of how I'd like to use such a function

```
if(arrayKeyVal(aClass::giveMeArray(),$myKey)) {
    do_something();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but:

```
$myValue = @$myArray[$myKey];
```

might work, though i honestly think you would be better off using

```
$myValue = (array_key_exists($myKey, $myArray)) ? $myArray[$myKey] : null;
```

Comment: sorry, not what i'm looking for, thank you for the reply though.

Comment: That should be what you're looking for.

Comment: No, the point is to not temporarily store the array in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You could return an [ArrayObject](http://www.php.net/~helly/php/ext/spl/classArrayObject.html), like so.

```
<?
class MyClass
{
    public static function getArray()
    {
        $arr = array('dave' => 1, 'bob' => 2, 'james' => 3);
        return new ArrayObject($arr, ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS);
    }
}

$var = MyClass::getArray()->bob;

?>
```

Comment: Right, but my question is if there is a native php function that already does it.

Answer (score 0):

$myValue = ($tmp = myClass::giveMeArray() && $tmp[$myKey]) ? $tmp[$myKey] : null;

It's not pretty, but it'll do it all in one line. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**: turns out I need to brush up on my PHP5. My answer below is incorrect and only applies to PHP4, since PHP5 has [method chaining](http://www.talkphp.com/advanced-php-programming/1163-php5-method-chaining.html).

---

PHP doesn't allow you to chain together the return statements from functions like in many other languages. eg, in Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('abc').style.color = "#fff";
```

It's a bit of a pain, but that's just how it is. The equivalent which you have to do in PHP is by storing temporary variables. Here's the above as you'd have to write it, if it were PHP: (obviously these aren't real PHP functions)

```
$myElement = $document->getElementById('abc');
$myElement->style->color = "#fff";
```

One little positive of this is that it makes debugging a wee bit easier.

Note that this only applies to functions: you can "chain" properties of objects:

```
$myObject->myArray[5]->anotherProperty->anotherArray[3]->anotherObject->aFunction();
```

so, in short, if you want to use the result of a function, you have to store it temporarily first

Comment: This is exactly the same conclusion I have come to as well.. Thank you for your reply

Comment: But that's bad advice; you CAN chain together return statements! Just google for "PHP Method Chaining."

Comment: try going to codepad.org and putting in:
<?php
class person { function printName() { print 'bob'; } }
function getPerson() { return new person(); }
getPerson()->printName();

Comment: I don't understand, did no one read what he wrote before voting down?

Comment: You can chain calls to the same object by returning the object in each call. Like so:

$x = new classX;
$x->write("bla")->write("ble")->save();

All you have to do to accomplish this is have the write method return the $this keyword

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you change the giveMeArray() function like so:

```
function giveMeArray($key = false) {
    $array = $whatever;
    $toret = null;
    if ($key) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $array)) {
            $toret = $array[$key];
        }
    } else {
        $toret = $array()
    }
    return $toret;
}
```

Then you can call it as

```
$arr = myClass::giveMeArray(); //To get the whole array
$value = myClass::giveMeArray($myKey); //To get the specific element
```