# Native PHP function that will grant me access to the string portions directly without having to create a temporary array?

Tags: php

I asked this question before, [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264441/does-a-native-php-5-function-exist-that-does-the-following-in-1-line) however I think I presented the problem poorly, and got quite a few replies that may have been useful to someone but did not address the actual question and so I pose the question again.

Is there a single-line native method in php that would allow me to do the following.
Please, please, I understand there are other ways to do this simple thing, but the question I present is does something exist **natively in PHP** that will **grant me access to the array** values directly **without having to create a temporary array**.

```
$rand_place = explode(",",loadFile("csvOf20000places.txt")){rand(0,1000)};
```

This is a syntax error, however ideally it would be great if this worked!

Currently, it seems unavoidable that one must create a temporary array, ie

**The following is what I want to avoid:**

```
$temporary_places_array = explode(",",loadFile("csvOf20000places.txt"));
$rand_place = $temporary_places_array[rand(0,1000)];
```

Also, i must note that my actual intentions are not to parse strings, or pull randomly from an array. **I simply want access into the string without a temporary variable**. This is just an example which i hope is easy to understand. There are many times service calls or things you do not have control over returns an array (such as the explode() function) and you just want access into it without having to create a temporary variable.

**NATIVELY NATIVELY NATIVELY, i know i can create a function that does it.**

Comment: No way to do it. This is one of the many brain-dead aspects of PHP's syntax.

Comment: This question is pointless because you simply cannot do what you wish to do natively.  You *must* go through a temporary array because otherwise there is no way to deal with a string as an array.

Comment: Isn't that entirely the reason to ask the question in the first place?

Kid: "Is it possible for a human being to fly using only his arms?"
You: "Your question is pointless because it's impossible for humans to fly with their arms"

Comment: I changed the title to actually reflect the question inside it.  Future people won't care that you asked a question before and the previous title provided no information as to the question.

Comment: Fortunately PHP is open source and you've identified something that's missing so the opportunity to add it is yours to embrace.  Even if the variable was anonymous and unnamed like you want you'd still end up with it taking up space in memory - and I don't know how scoping works in PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, there is no way to do that natively.**

You can, however:

1.- Store the unavoidable array instead of the string. Given PHP's limitation this is what makes most sense in my opinion.

Also, don't forget you can [unset()](http://php.net/unset)

2.- Use strpos() and friends to parse the string into what you need, as shown in other answers I won't paste here.

3.- Create a function.

Comment: In your example, you gave yourself the liberty of making $places a temporary array .... which defeats the entire purpose of this question.

Comment: I'm actually suggesting you use an array instead of the CSV string. I say so in the third paragraph. The idea is to avoid storing the string, because I understand that your concern is duplication of storage.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native PHP method of doing this.

You could make a function like this:

```
function array_value($array, $key) {
    return $array[$key];
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
$places = "alabama,alaska,arizona .... zimbabway"; 
$random_place = array_value(explode(",", $places), rand(0, 1000));
```

Comment: i know i can create a function that does this...  my question is specifically address a native php method.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's poor form to answer a question with a question, but why are you concerned about this?  Is it a nitpick, or an optimization question?  The Zend engine will optimize this away.

However, I'd point out you don't have to create a temporary variable *necessarily*:

```
$rand_place = explode(",",loadFile("csvOf20000places.txt"));
$rand_place = $rand_place[rand(0,1000)];
```

Because of type mutability, you could reuse the variable.  Of course, you're still not skipping a step.

Comment: I ask simply because I don't want the extra line of code, lets say it was for a compeititon to see who could use the least amount of characters to do something (yea you'd probalby want to use perl and not php) but that's why i'm asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
list($rand_place) = array_slice(explode(',', loadFile("csvOf20000places.txt")), array_rand(explode(',', loadFile("csvOf20000places.txt"))), 1);
```

**EDIT:** Ok, you're right. The question is *very* hard to understand but, I think this is it. The code above will pull random items from the csv file but, to just pull whatever you want out, use this:

```
list($rand_place) = array_slice(explode(',', loadFile("csvOf20000places.txt")), {YOUR_NUMBER}, 1);
```

Replace the holder with the numeric key of the value you want to pull out.

Comment: Damn, I spent some time on this. How is it now the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If it's memory concerns, there are other ways of going about this that don't split out into an array. But no, there is nothing builtin to handle this sort of situation.

As an alternative, you might try:

```
$pos = 0;
$num = 0;
while(($pos = strpos($places, ',', $pos+1)) !== false) {$num++;}
$which = rand(0, $num);
$num = 0;
while($num <= $which) {$pos = strpos($places, ',', $pos+1);}
$random_place = substr($places, $pos, strpos($places, ',', $pos+1));
```

I havn't tested this, so there may be a few off-by-one issues in it, but you get the idea. This could be made shorter (and quicker) by cacheing the positions that you work out in the first loop, but this brings you back to the memory issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<?php
function foo() {
    return new ArrayObject(explode(",", "zero,one,two"));
}
echo foo()->offsetGet(1);    // "one"
?>
```

Sadly you **can't** do this:

```
echo (new ArrayObject(explode(",", "zero,one,two")))->offsetGet(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent a great deal of last year researching advanced CSV parsing for PHP and I admit it would be nice to randomly seek at will on a file.   One of my semi-deadend's was to scan through a known file and make an index of the position of all known \n's that were not at the beginning of the line.

```
   //Grab and load our index
$index = unserialize(file_get_contents('somefile.ext.ind'));
//What it looks like
$index = array( 0 => 83, 1 => 162, 2 => 178, ....);

$fHandle = fopen("somefile.ext",'RB');
$randPos = rand(0, count($index));
fseek($fHandle, $index[$randPos]);
$line = explode(",", fgets($fHandle));
```

Tha's the only way I could see it being done anywhere close to what you need.  As for creating the index, that's rudimentary stuff.

```
$fHandle = fopen('somefile.ext','rb');
$index = array();
for($i = 0; false !== ($char = fgetc($fHandle)); $i++){
      if($char === "\n") $index[] = $i;     
}
```